# Returning customize Array value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample of code that returns each value in an array, in order. I have used `forEach()`. Is there any way to return value in customize array.

I made some function for split `text-area` value to all textarea and query using text string. I am able to success. But Some Problem. Below Example.

1. Type to `Filed1` string like:
     
    `GFSD`
   `65897542`
2. Then Click Split Button. Output: part all value to reaming text area.
3. Put **GF** value to **Input Character** Filed. Output: **6589**
4. My Question is When i put value like **GF** then output **6589**. And when put **FG** then also same output **6589** instead of **8965**. If any solution Pls help me out. I wish to the Character strictly follow number.

Sample of Code:

```
$('#output1').focus(()=>{
    var a=document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    var str = $('#ccMain').val();
    var first = str[0];
    var second = str[1];
    console.log(first," ", second)
    var str='';
    a.forEach(e=>e.value.includes(first)||e.value.includes(second)?str+=e.value.substr(1,e.value.length):false)
        $('#output1').val(str);
    })
```

```js
 function splitText() {
      var textAreas = [];
      //Put all of the textareas into an array for easy access
      for(let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      textAreas.push(document.getElementById(`value${i}`));
      }
      //Read the text from text1 and split it at a new line
      var text = textAreas[0].value;
      var [line1, line2] = text.split(/\r?\n/)
      for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var combinedText = line1.substring(i, i+1) + line2.substring(i*2, (i+1)*2)
      textAreas[i].value = combinedText;
      }
      }
      $('#output').focus(()=>{
      var a=document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
      var str = $('#ccMain').val();
      var first = str[0];
      var second = str[1];
      console.log(first," ", second)
      var str='';
      a.forEach(e=>e.value.includes(first)||e.value.includes(second)?str+=e.value.substr(1,e.value.length):false)
      $('#output').val(str);
      })
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test Demo</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <label>Filed1 </label>
      <textarea id="value1"></textarea>
     
      <label>Filed2:</label>
      <textarea id="value2"></textarea>
      
      <label>Filed3:</label>
      <textarea id="value3"></textarea>
      
      <label>Filed4:</label>
      <textarea id="value4"></textarea>
      
      <button onclick="splitText()">Split!</button>
      <br>
      <label>Input Character:</label>
      <br>
     
      <input type="text" id="ccMain"  >
     
      <textarea id="output"></textarea>
      
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: please add the data, you have and the wanted result.

Comment: i added sir, waiting for your replay

Comment: That is quite a big change from the original question though

Comment: i have not change any, someone want data.So i put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `map` to put the correspondence between letter and digits

```
$('#output').focus(()=>{
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    var map = new Map(Array.from(textareas, area => [area.value[0], area.value.slice(1)]));
    var str = Array.from($('#ccMain').val(), c => map.get(c)).join``;
    $('#output').val(str);
});
```

```js
function splitText() {
    //Put all of the textareas into an array for easy access
    var textAreas = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        textAreas.push(document.getElementById(`value${i}`));
    }
    //Read the text from text1 and split it at a new line
    var text = textAreas[0].value;
    var [line1, line2] = text.split(/\r?\n/);
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var combinedText = line1.substring(i, i+1) + line2.substring(i*2, (i+1)*2)
        textAreas[i].value = combinedText;
    }
}

$('#output').focus(()=>{
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    var map = new Map(Array.from(textareas, area => [area.value[0], area.value.slice(1)]));
    var str = Array.from($('#ccMain').val(), c => map.get(c)).join``;
    $('#output').val(str);
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <label>Filed1 </label>
  <textarea id="value1"></textarea>
 
  <label>Filed2:</label>
  <textarea id="value2"></textarea>
  
  <label>Filed3:</label>
  <textarea id="value3"></textarea>
  
  <label>Filed4:</label>
  <textarea id="value4"></textarea>
  
  <button onclick="splitText()">Split!</button>
  <br>
  <label>Input Character:</label>
  <br>
 
  <input type="text" id="ccMain"  >
 
  <textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Awesome! Pls don't mind. I want to give u some tips.Because I am very happy. btc addrs pls

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to be a bit more careful in your code here, ou are defining `str` twice in your code block.

As far as what you want to achieve, I guess you want to go for something like

```
str = Array.from( a )
  .filter( e => e.value.includes( first ) || e.value.includes( second ) )
  .map( e => e.value.substring( 1 ) )
  .join('')
```

this would first create an array from your nodes, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and then you can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the values you are really interested in, after which you can take the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) of the values (you don't need the `e.value.length`, as this is the same as when you are just defining a `startIndex` in the `substring` method

Comment: @nurislam well to be fair, it only deals with the for each in the original question, so you would still need to handle the result. Not working is also not useful, could you be more explicit?

Comment: i wanna give u $100 tips. can u help me pls

Comment: @nurislam Well, I tested your current code with the suggested input you gave, and in both cases I got your desired output, so I am not sure what is wrong. It could be that you should do something similar like you do in the split function, to get the fields in the correct order